# Stop and Remove Container does not work sometimes

Tags: shell, docker, sh

I have a shell script .sh to stop and remove my running containers, which usually works very well. But in one out of ten times the `docker rm` command seems to be executed before `docker stop` finished, so it raises an error that the container is still running. What can i do to prevent that error?

```
docker stop nostalgic_shirley
docker rm nostalgic_shirley
```

Output

```
nostalgic_shirley
nostalgic_shirley
Error response from daemon: You cannot remove a running container xxxx. Stop the container before attempting removal or force remove
```

if i then try to use `docker rm nostalgic_shirley` again, it works fine.

I should not use `docker stop --force` as the shutdown should be gracefully

Comment: docker rm -f nostalgic_shirley

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really care to stop the container before deleting:

```
 docker stop nostalgic_shirley
 while [ ! -z "$(docker ps | grep nostalgic_shirley)" ]; do sleep 2; done
 docker rm nostalgic_shirley
```

If not, simply delete it with "force" option (You can even skip stopping):

```
 docker rm -f nostalgic_shirley
```

Comment: Thank you! i have to try the sleep option! Still i am wondering why this is necessary, and does not wait with the next command before it finished stopping.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have by any chance any other process/user login to container sometimes when it did not stopped ? 
Since as you mentioned this is something not happening frequently : have you checked the state of environment when this happens for parameters like CPU utilization, memory etc.

Have you tried

a) stopping the container with overriding -t flag

Use "-t" flag of "docker stop" command

```
-t, --time=10
       Seconds to wait for stop before killing it
```

b) Use "-f" flag of "docker rm" command

```
-f, --force[=false]
       Force the removal of a running container (uses SIGKILL)
```

Comment: Thank you! a) This could work (it is possible that the issue only arises after the default 10 seconds) b) i updated my question, that forcing does not work